# Multiple span elements for p:commandButton

Tags: primefaces, commandbutton

I'd like to format multiple Texts for a commandButton, something like '*text1*    **text2**      text3', all in an different format.

For this, I thought of multiple span elements for PrimeFaces (7.0) commandButton.

Does anybody know how to do this?
Is it possible anyway?

I tried it with

```
<p:commandButton...>
    <span style="...">text1</span>
    <span style="...">text2</span>
    <span style="...">text3</span>
</p:commandButton>
```

but this isn't the solution.

@kukeltje

I found this site and testet it before asking this question. 
It ended up in

```
<button     
    id="..." 
    name="..." 
    class="..." 
    onclick="" 
    type="submit" 
    role="button" 
    aria-disabled="false">

    <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">ui-button</span>
</button>

<span>text1</span>
<span>text2</span>
<span>text3</span>
```

Comment: In what way isn't it the solution?  Does it create ww3? What does it end up like in the browser? Greek? Hindi? According to https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=25079 something like this worked (searching for this yourself and mentioning it is appreciated)

Comment: And what if you **also** add a `value="dummyText"` to the commandButton? Still not ok? And what if you use a `div` instead of span? And what if you wrap the three spans in a div (`<div><span style="...">text1</span>
    <span style="...">text2</span>
    <span style="...">text3</span></div>` or some other wrapping element? Still fails?

Comment: Same behaviour, except that button displays the value.